Getting docker-compose to work on Windows Server 2019
I'm trying to get docker-compose to work on Windows Server 2019 Build 1809. I know it's not officially supported so I used some workarounds to install docker-compose and the docker engine. The part that I'm stuck at is why docker-compose is not working when I switch it to a windows image?
The error message:
ERROR: for app  'ContainerConfig'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "docker-compose", line 3, in <module>
  File "compose\cli\main.py", line 81, in main
  File "compose\cli\main.py", line 203, in perform_command
  File "compose\metrics\decorator.py", line 18, in wrapper
  File "compose\cli\main.py", line 1186, in up
  File "compose\cli\main.py", line 1166, in up
  File "compose\project.py", line 697, in up
  File "compose\parallel.py", line 108, in parallel_execute
  File "compose\parallel.py", line 206, in producer
  File "compose\project.py", line 679, in do
  File "compose\service.py", line 579, in execute_convergence_plan
  File "compose\service.py", line 499, in _execute_convergence_recreate
  File "compose\parallel.py", line 108, in parallel_execute
  File "compose\parallel.py", line 206, in producer
  File "compose\service.py", line 494, in recreate
  File "compose\service.py", line 612, in recreate_container
  File "compose\service.py", line 330, in create_container
  File "compose\service.py", line 921, in _get_container_create_options
  File "compose\service.py", line 960, in _build_container_volume_options
  File "compose\service.py", line 1548, in merge_volume_bindings
  File "compose\service.py", line 1579, in get_container_data_volumes
KeyError: 'ContainerConfig'
[19196] Failed to execute script docker-compose

dockerfile:
# python base image enabling us to run pip
FROM python:3.9-windowsservercore:1809-amd64 

# Set the working directory in the container
WORKDIR "C:\\Git\\test"

# Copy the current directory contents into the container
COPY . .

# RUN pip install --upgrade pip
# RUN pip install pyodbc

# Install any needed packages specified in requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

CMD ["python", "./sms_main.py"]


docker-compose.yml:
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile_windows
    volumes:
      - "C:\Git\test"
    env_file:
      - env
    command: python3 ./main.py

Since this is such a simple Dockerfile, I'm confused at what could be going on.
Things I've tried:

Set experimental to true in docker.config json file
Uninstalled and re-installed docker and docker-compose
Tried adding "-amd64" in the tag according to some docs
Tried using a single backslash instead of "\" in case it was something with that
Enabled all the hyper-v and hypervisor stuff in Server Manager


Did you manage to get this to work? I installed docker on WinServer2019 but can't get compose to work.

Not on windows server, right now we're looking at using Azure ACR and deploying the container directly
